# Solution of A Triangle

Tags: trigonometry

This problem is found in S.L. Loney's book on Plane Trigonometry.

The question is: to find the acute angles of a right angled triangle, the hypothenuse of which is 4 times the perpendicular dropped from the opposite angle.

I believe I've spent too much time trying to solve the problem. Guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.  Note:  I wouldn't expect the angles to be pleasant, if that's the reason you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let the perpendicular be $x$, hypothenuse is $4x$. Let $\alpha$ be one of the acute angles. We have $x\cot \alpha+ x \cot(90^\circ-\alpha)=4x$ or  $\cot \alpha+  \tan \alpha=4$. Can you solve the last equation?

Comment: I found $\alpha$ to be equal to both $15$ degrees and $75$ degrees. I believe this result shows that there were two acute angles? I thank you much for your help!

Comment: @Camelot823: Any right triangle has two acute angles that add up to 90 degrees. So yes, angle $\alpha$ can have two values but the triangle will be the same (for any particular value of $x$).